# Setting up AWS ELB with backend express app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express

I have a web project I am building for fun.  It is react, express, mongodb

I currently have an aws domain we will call foo.com that my react app is linked to.  I am using S3 and cloudfront to route foo.com as my react app sitting in S3.

I created an SSL cert for foo.com.

That all works

Now on an EC2 instance I have a Express.js app that I am using as a rest server.  So my react app uses my elastic ip to call using REST on my EC2 instance.

Since I added SSL to my react app it now will not allow non SSL calls into my api so I am trying to fix that.

I setup an ELB and used my foo.com cert (Mistake?) pointing at my EC2 and opened port 80 and 443  via security group, all works. Except my cert is for foo.com. and my backend server is just setup to use elastic up.  Or I guess now the load balancer URL. So I get an invalid certificate name error if I try to load the URL to my express app via the load balancer URL.

How do I use SSL to have my react app make http calls to my express backend.  Do I create a new cert?  The cert seems to want a DNS name like foo.com but my backend server is just an elastic ip.

Not really sure how to tie all this together I think I am 90% where I need to be.?

Need to get my react app on S3 with a cert and DNS name foo.com to talk to my rest server (express) on EC2 instance using just elastic IP? or Load Balancer URL?  What do I do for a cert for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the cert to the load balancer, and point a domain at the load balancer. Something like `api.foo.com`. You do this by creating a CNAME record in your DNS provider, that points to the load balancer's DNS name. Then have your React app make calls to your API at that domain name. You can create the certs for free in AWS Certificate Manager that will attach to an ELB.

The cert you add to the load balancer will either need to be for `api.foo.com` or `*.foo.com`.

Comment: So do I need to buy/register a new domain?  Same as I did for my react domain name?

Comment: I understand I add a new cname with api.foo.com to my existing domain I am trying that now the domain is propagating.  I will post updates

Comment: I have it setup the way it states above but I am getting 502 bad gateway going to https://api.foo.com.    (not my real domain). aws logs.                                             <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>

Comment: Were you able to hit your API through the load balancer before you setup the CNAME record? It sounds like there's some sort of access exception happening in your API code.

Comment: So let me see if I can explain this.  I had react running in docker on the same EC2 and pulled it out to S3 and added SSL at that point I could no longer call my api because it was not SSL.  So I started setting up the ELB so I could use SSL on my express app.  I have not been able to connect since I did that.  I am not sure if its my app or ELB.  The elb Log says - <Message>Access Denied</Message>. On screen using my DNS name I get 502 bad gateway.  How do I debug if I have an app issue or a ELB issue? My app is just express running with node.

Comment: ps on docker container 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp. I can with non ssl hit a REST endpoint through dns.   myapp.com/api/getall.  returns data.   SSL is 502 bad gateway.  I see health checks hitting docker for http but nothing for https.  Just failed health checks. Express is just using node and has 4 REST endpoints to talk to a mongodb.  I did nothing except open 443 with docker compose. How do I know if its the app not setup correct or my ELB.  No clear error one way or the other.

Comment: Your docker container/ec2 server doesn't have an SSL certificate installed does it? The SSL certificate is on the load balancer. You shouldn't open port 443 on the server (just opening the port doesn't magically create an HTTPS server). You need to configure the load balancer to connect to the target server over port 80. Until the load balancer health checks start passing you won't be able to get any further.

Comment: So im not 100% sure I get that.  I have 2 listeners on my ELB one for http one for https both point to a target group.  My target group uses port 80 for http and port 443 for https.  Your saying my https target group should use port 80

Comment: A target group can only have one port, so when you say "My target group uses port 80 for http and port 443 for https" It sounds like you actually have 2 target groups. The load balancer will be terminating the SSL connection, Port 443 will only be used between the web browser and the load balancer. The load balancer will only communicate with your EC2 instance within your private VPC network over port 80 (because the EC2 instance doesn't have an SSL certificate installed on it). You should only have one target group, and it should be using port 80. Attach that to both listeners.

Comment: That was it. I removed a target group and updated my listeners to both use my port 80 target group.  I knew I had no certs on my server but I had it in my head I needed 443. Thank you for hanging in there with me.  One fight down on to the next.

Comment: @ducati1212 please upvote and mark the answer as accepted if my answer solved your problem.